# DSL, XamlDOM (.NET 4 Beta) and extending vs2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xaml, visual-studio-2010, dsl

I have the following situation: I want to develop a DSL. To generate the code, I would need the help of the XamlDOM Implementation, which offers static analysis and manipulation of XAML Code. Unfortunately, XamlDOM can only be used with .NET 4.

I wouldn't have a problem using the vs2010 and .NET 4.0 Betas, but I need to target the DSL for vs2008. Do I have any solution or alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the DSL forum on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dslvsarchx/threads